# How to check if array values are in a range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**My code:**

if column A:A contains "term1" or "term2", set in the corresponding row in column B:B the value "send email".

```
function col_email() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
var r = s.getRange('A:A');
var v = r.getValues();

var searchTerm = 'term1';
var searchTerm2 = 'term2';

for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {

    if(v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
     var row = (i+1)
     s.getRange('B'+row).setValue("send email");   
    }

    if(v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm2) > -1) {
     var row = (i+1)
     s.getRange('B'+row).setValue("send email");   
    }
}

};
```

**My code works fine but I would like to make it easier to manage:**

if column A:A contain one of the values in the array `searchTerm`, set in the corresponding row in column B:B the value "send email".

```
function col_email() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
var r = s.getRange('A:A');
var v = r.getValues();

var searchTerm = ["term1","term2","term3","term4"];

for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {

    if(v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
     var row = (i+1)
     s.getRange('B'+row).setValue("send email");   
    }

}

};
```

Some advice on how to fix the code above would really help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
function col_email() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
var searchTerm = ["term1","term2","term3","term4"];
s.getRange('A:A').getValues().forEach( (row, ind) => {
if(searchTerm.indexOf(row[0].toString()) > -1) {
s.getRange(ind + 1, 2).setValue('Send Email')
}
})
}
```

EDIT: To deal with partial matches, try

```
function col_email() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
var searchTerm = ["term1","term2","term3","term4"];
s.getRange('A:A').getValues().forEach( (row, ind) => {
searchTerm.forEach( t => {
if(row[0].toString().indexOf(t) > -1) {
s.getRange(ind + 1, 2).setValue('Send Email')
}})
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's works! but only in case of exact match. Is it possible set the value "send email" if the row in A:A contain one of the search terms. Hope that make sense. Thanks alot.